# visual studio code displaying the line from the opening curly brace, then closing curly brace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting, highlight

When I worked in visual studio code on linux, there was such a strip from one curly brace to another. I do not know what was responsible for its display, maybe some kind of extension. But after switching to Windows, I don't see them anymore, although I seem to have installed the same extensions. I do not know what it is called and how to return it, maybe someone knows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `editor.guides.bracketPairs` setting. The default value is `false` when it's not specified, so you must have set it to `true` in your user settings.json file or in your workspace `.vscode/settings.json` file. Find out where you set it and either set it to `false` or remove that line to get `false` as the default value.